# Can I use a router which has just one working interface?

Tags: ethernet, interface

I have a Mikrotik RB532 router with three Ethernet ports. One of the ports supports PoE and the other two don't. The main point is that LAN2 and LAN3 interfaces are broken. Can the device still be used, for example, to connect a few PCs to the Internet? In my case, I intend to use the router as a Hotspot server.

```
Software:

RouterOS 6.32.2
RouterBoard Firmware 2.18
```

[image: Mikrotik RB532 Board]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the device supports VLANs, it could be used as a router-on-a-stick to route between the VLANs. You would need a switch which also supports VLANs.

The connection from the switch to the router would be a trunk carrying all the VLANs supported by the switch. Place the WAN connection on a switch port which is set to the VLAN used for the WAN, and any other ports would be in another VLAN for the LAN. In fact, you could have multiple LAN VLANs for different LAN segments.